# hibernate many to relationship

Tags: hibernate

i would like to maintain many to one relationship with two table on the database. I am using Oracle database and Hibernate. The tables are **application** and **instrument**. first one has two column : id and event. second table has three column : id, type and **application**. the hibernate mapping for application is like :

```
    <class name="com.tpdadmin.entity.Application" table="tpd_application_table">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Long">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">tpd_application_table_sequence</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="event" column="event" type="java.lang.String" />
</class>
```

And for instrument is like :

```
<class name="com.tpdadmin.entity.Instrument" table="tpd_instrument">
    <id name="id" column="id" type="java.lang.Long">
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">tpd_instrument_sequence</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="type" column="type" type="java.lang.String" />
    <many-to-one name="applicationTable" class="com.tpdadmin.entity.Application" column="application_table_id" insert="false" update="false" />
    </class>
```

i want to maintain relationship between these two entities. but with these hibernate mapping, i am not able to make their relationship. so guys please help me out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281451/use-the-one-to-many-or-many-to-one

Comment: one **application** can contain multiple **instrument**. and one **instrument** must contain only one **application**. so i need to maintain many to one relationship in the instrument hbm file. but still i am not able to persist their relationship in the database. please show me the ray.

Comment: why do you have insert and update set to false?

Comment: thanks aishwarya, your question helps me to find the solution. the mistake i was doing is to set update -> false. the moment i set update -> true, hibernate starts saving the relationship between the instrument and the application.